# error de referencia circular entre security config y un controlador - spring

Tags: java, spring-security

Tengo un problema en al momento de desplegar un proyecto. Desde el IDE el código compila y se ejecuta la aplicación correctamente, pero al momento de ejecutar el .war desde una consola me genera el siguiente error:

*org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'usuarioController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'enc'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'bcrypt'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'passwordEncoder': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?*

**Comparto el controlador**

```
@Controller
public class UsuarioController {

  @Autowired
  private UsuarioService usuarioService;

  @Autowired
  private FormatoCampo fc;

  @Autowired
  private final BCryptPasswordEncoder ENCODER = new BCryptPasswordEncoder(4);

  @GetMapping("/signup")
  public String goToSignin(Model model) {
    Usuario user = new Usuario();
    model.addAttribute("user", user);
    return "signup";
  }

  @PostMapping("/signup")
  public String userRegister(@ModelAttribute("user") Usuario user) {
    try {
      Rol rol = new Rol();
      rol.setId(2);
      user.setRol(rol);
      user.setEnable(true);
      user.setPassword(ENCODER.encode(user.getPassword()));
      user.setNombre(fc.formatearNoNumeros(user.getNombre()));
      user.setApellido(fc.formatearNoNumeros(user.getApellido()));
      usuarioService.addUsuario(user);
      return "redirect:/signup?success=true";
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("com.torneos.backend.controllers.UsuarioController.userRegister()" + e.getMessage());
      return "redirect:/signup?error=true";
    }
  }
}
```

**La clase SecurityConfig:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

String[] resources = new String[] {
    "/include/**", "/css/**", "/icons/**", "/img/**", "/js/**", "/template/layout/**", "/assets/**",
    "/webjars/**"
};

@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@Autowired
private BCryptPasswordEncoder bcrypt;

@Bean
public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
  BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder(4);
  return bCryptPasswordEncoder;
}

public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
    throws Exception {
  auth.userDetailsService(userService).passwordEncoder(bcrypt);
}

@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers(resources).permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/", "/torneos", "/signup", "/jugadores").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/admin**").hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_MASTER")
    .antMatchers("/master**").hasAuthority("ROLE_MASTER")
    .antMatchers("/user**").hasAuthority("ROLE_USER")
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
    .formLogin()
    .loginPage("/login")
    .permitAll()
    .defaultSuccessUrl("/default")
    .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
    .usernameParameter("username")
    .passwordParameter("password")
    .and()
    .logout()
    .permitAll()
    .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout");
  return http.build();
  }
}
```

Agradezco mucho si algien me puede ayudar a dar una solución a este problema.

Answer (score 1):

El problema está en la clase `SecurityConfig` y no está relacionado con el controlador `UsuarioController`.

Lo que ocurre es que el campo `bcrypt`, que es de tipo `BCryptPasswordEncoder`, está anotado con `@Autowired` por lo que Spring intentará encontrar un *bean* de tipo `BCryptPasswordEncoder` para inyectarlo en dicho campo. Ahora bien, el *bean* que puede satisfacer esa inyección de dependnecia solicitada lo estás definiendo en la misma clase `SecurityConfig` a través del método `passwordEncoder()` por lo que falla el proceso al intentar inyectar un *bean* en la misma clase que lo define.

Para solucionarlo te recomiendo que elimines el `@Autowired` del campo `bcrypt` y que lo inicialices por tu cuenta. De este modo sí podrías usarlo en varios métodos de la clase `SecurityConfig` si así lo necesitas.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    // ...

    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bcrypt = new BCryptPasswordEncoder(4);

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return bcrypt;
    }

    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userService).passwordEncoder(bcrypt);
    }

    // ...
}
```

---

**BONUS**

No creo que esto funcione en la clase `UsuarioCoontroller`:

```java
@Autowired
private final BCryptPasswordEncoder ENCODER = new BCryptPasswordEncoder(4);
```

Debería ser así:

```java
@Autowired
private BCryptPasswordEncoder ENCODER;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la alaración, efectivamente ese era el problema. Ya todo funciona correctamente

Comment: Me alegro que te funcionara!!